# как из iframe выполнить функцию, которая находится в родительском окне

Tags: jquery, javascript, iframe

У меня есть кнопка, на которую повешено событие

```
open("_другой_сайт_","DisplayWindow","toolbar=yes,directories=no,menubar=yes,status=yes");
```

затем в окне происходит редирект на мой сайт. На этой странице нужно выполнить функцию, которая находится в родительском окне.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запустить функцию f, которая находится в родительском окне для **окна** можно так

```
window.opener.f()
```

для **iframe** можно так

```
window.parent.f()
```

Comment: Большое спасибо. Я что-то перепутал iframe с окном. Теперь всё заработало.